# Trying to open a new activity from AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
.....
}

public void onEnabled (Context contex){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ReadName.class);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

well, I tried just system.out.println(" ") it works, means it is showing on LogCat, but is it possible to open a new activity from this method onEnabled (Context contex) Thanks

---

I am trying this way but it is not showing :s me a new activity onload widget,

```
public void onEnabled (Context contex){
    System.out.println("new task flag");
    Intent i = new Intent(contex, ReadName.class);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    contex.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Also give a try by setting the flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Link to this documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is overridder method of AppWidgetProvider  and ClickOneActivity is my activity where i want to move...
Check the code it will help u...

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, ClickOneActivity.class);
        configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, ButtonWidget.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
        active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button 1");
        //when you will click button1 the message "Message for Button 1" will appear as a notification
//you can do whatever you want anyway on the press of this button
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, actionPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_two, configPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }
```

All The Best

Comment: I am trying this way but it is not showing :s me a new activity onload widget,

public void onEnabled (Context contex){
    System.out.println("new task flag");
    Intent i = new Intent(contex, ReadName.class);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    contex.startActivity(i);
}